# Sequelize: order-by doesn't seem to work on aggregated output while using multiple joins

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've been trying to order the results by total no. of all reviews given for a particular seller's store.

All associations are defined but when I tried order by on avg(ratings) or count(id) [here id is id of alias named 'seller_details'], it gives me an error. I have tried many ways like using Sequelize.col() and giving all models names; using Sequelize.literal() but none works.

```
const data = await UserFavoriteStores.findAndCountAll({
      where: {
        customer_id: userId
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: SellerStoreDetail,
          required: false,
          include: [
            {
              model: StoreReviews,
              required: false,
              attributes: [],
              as: 'seller_details'
            }
          ],
          attributes: {
            include: [
              [
                Sequelize.fn(
                  'count',
                  Sequelize.col('favStoreData.seller_details.id')
                ),
                'totalReviewCount'
              ],
              [
                Sequelize.fn(
                  'AVG',
                  Sequelize.col('favStoreData.seller_details.rating')
                ),
                'avgRating'
              ]
            ]
          },
          as: 'favStoreData'
        }
      ],
      group: ['user_favorite_stores.id', 'favStoreData.id'],
      limit: limit,
      offset: skip,
      subQuery: false
    });
```

Comment: please share the entire error message.

Comment: error message is : "column favStoreData.totalReviewCount does not exist"